# Django-watermark: URL not directing properly

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I successfully installed [django-watermark](https://github.com/codekoala/django-watermark). After setting it up, I load up the webpage. On Chrome browser, it's working fine and images are watermarked. On Mozilla firefox and Opera, it's not displaying any images not even the one I uploaded. After checking the source code, I found out that '\' after "watermarked" is the one causing the problem.

```
<img src=/media//photos/watermarked\3bbb94f57f32d2796ea59adc86310a12752f0088.jpg>
```

Template

```
 <img src={{ MEDIA_URL }}/{{post.main_view|watermark:"hall,position=tl,opacity=90"}}>
```

I've been looking for a way to fix this, yet no success, any idea on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to fixed this by digging into the watermark folder. watermarker/templatetags/watermark.py

Check for the below code, delete it and paste this:

```
#100   basedir = '%s/watermarked/' % os.path.dirname(url)
```